# unsigned int64 в postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Как в postgresql сделать колонку с типом unsigned int64? По дефолту такого типа нет. Какие есть решения?

Comment: Да, BIGINT бывает только знаковый... а с какой целью? а то ведь можно использовать DECIMAL/NUMERIC соотв. размерности, например, или BYTEA.

Comment: @Akina с флотами не хочется возиться. Понял, спасибо

Comment: DECIMAL/NUMERIC - это ни разу не FLOAT/DOUBLE/REAL.

Comment: @Akina https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/datatype-numeric это вещественное число

Comment: "И, боже вас сохрани, не читайте до обеда советских газет." Применительно к данному случаю - кривых переводов. То, что переведено как "вещественное число с указанной точностью", на самом деле "user-specified precision, exact". Тогда как вещественные - это inexact. Полюбопытствуйте - как они хранятся, почему длины частей задаются отдельно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В postgresql нет unsigned типов данных. Если вам нужно ограничение на минимальное значение - то добавьте `check constraint`, например во время create table:

```
create table foo (
  i bigint check (i >= 0)
);
```

Если вам не хватает диапазона значений `bigint` - то используйте `numeric`.

---

Почему их нет - сошлюсь на core разработчика postgresql в пояснении [к релевантному расширению](https://github.com/petere/pguint):

> Support for unsigned integer types and smaller integer types has been
> one of the more common outstanding feature request for PostgreSQL.
> Inclusion of additional integer types into the core is typically
> rejected with the argument that it would make the type system too
> complicated and fragile. The experience from writing this module
> suggests: That is not wrong. Another argument, either explicit or
> implicit, is that it is a lot of work. Again: true.
>
> The combination of the requirements of the SQL standard and the type
> system of PostgreSQL effectively create a situation where you need to
> provide a comprehensive set of operators and functions for each
> combination of numeric types. So for the three standard integer types,
> that's 9 "+" operators, 9 "<" operators, and so on. And with 3 + 5 = 8
> types, well, you do the math. This module solves that problem by
> generating most of the code automatically.

Реализация unsigned типов потребует реализацию очень большого числа операторов для взаимодействия с другими типами данных - это негативная сторона впечатляющих возможностей postgresql для расширения.